# Unable to download list of all Videos on Dailymotion

Tags: python, dailymotion-api

I am using Dailymotion API to get the list of all videos on my channel. Although my channel has more than 3000 videos, I am able to scan and download the list of only 1000 videos. Please help.

Channel link: https://www.dailymotion.com/prashant_advait

Below is the code:

```
import dailymotion

d = dailymotion.Dailymotion()

d.set_grant_type(
            "password",
            api_key=_API_KEY_HINDI,
            api_secret=_API_SECRET_HINDI,
            scope=["manage_videos"],
            info={"username": _USERNAME_HINDI, "password": _PASSWORD_HINDI},
        )


page = 1

while(True):
    api_call = '/me/videos?fields=id,title,url,tags&limit=100&page=' + str(page)
    r = d.get(api_call)

    print(r)

    if r['has_more'] is False:
        break

    page = r['page']+1
```

*At page 10, the GET request has 'has_more' field set to False and no more videos are there.*

**Below call gives no result:**

```
api_call = '/me/videos?fields=id,title,url&limit=100&page=' + str(11)
r = d.get(api_call)
```

**Result:**

{'page': 11,
 'limit': 100,
 'explicit': False,
 'total': 0,
 'has_more': False,
 'list': []}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameters like `created_after` and `sort`=`old` to reduce the set of videos returned by the API. Once arrived to the last video of the last page, use the `created_time` field value to perform a new API call from this date.

Example:

1. https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos?fields=id,title,url,created_time&limit=100&page=10&sort=old
2. https://api.dailymotion.com/me/videos?fields=id,title,url,created_time&limit=100&page=1&sort=old&created_after=123456789

If this is not enough to browse all your catalog please reach out to your Dailymotion contact to find a solution.